# Coldfusion: Set function for object

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I have an model object;

```
building= model("tb_buildings");
building.myFunction() = function(){return false;};
```

Initially this object has no methods, I am trying to created a method for it called myFunction() and assign it a value of false; I tried the anonymous function approach but it give me an error;

```
Cannot assign a value to a function
```

Is this possible?

Comment: *create a method for it called myFunction()* FWIW, the actual name of the function is "myFunction", not "myFunction()". By adding the parenthesis, you are actually *invoking* the function (with no parameters), rather than assigning something to a variable named:  "myFunction". Hence the error "....Cannot assign a value to a function".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To set a variable to be a function you should

```
building.myFunction = function(){ return false; };
```